# Is MPL pos an undocumented metafunction?

Tags: c++, boost, find, position, boost-mpl

There is the following example code in the [BOOST MPL documentation of the `find` algorithm](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/find.html):

```
typedef vector<char,int,unsigned,long,unsigned long> types;
typedef find<types,unsigned>::type iter;
...
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_RELATION( iter::pos::value, ==, 2 );
```

However, I cannot find the documentation for the iterator's `pos` metafunction. Can I use it reliably?

I'd like to use it somehow as:

```
typedef vector<type1, type2, type3> types;

template <typename T>
void File::write(T value) {
    BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((contains<types, T>));
    unsigned typeID = find<types, T>::type::pos::value;
    fstr << typeID << value;
}
```

to store the type information into a file together with the value itself.

**EDIT**

Thanks Potatoswatter for the answer, this solution seems to work:

```
template <typename S, typename T>
struct pos : distance< typename begin<S>::type, typename find<S, T>::type >
{};

...
    unsigned typeID = pos<types, T>::value;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Metafunctions look like `fn< iter >::value`. That is simply a member of the iterator type.

Inituitively, I would say that member is specific to iterators resulting from `find` or functions like it. In any case, as you say, it is undocumented. Do not assume that every iterator has a `pos` member.

The `distance` metafunction should provide this functionality, although it might be slower.