# boost::mpl::vector - getting to a type's base-offset

Tags: c++, algorithm, containers, boost-mpl, template-meta-programming

Is it possible to get at the offset of a `mpl::vector` after performing a `mpl::find<seq,type>` on it ?

Put differently I want to do the compile time equavalent of:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  typedef std::vector<int> v_type;
  v_type v_int(3);

  v_int[0] = 1;
  v_int[1] = 2;
  v_int[2] = 3;

  v_type::iterator it= std::find(  v_int.begin() ,v_int.end(),3);

  std::cout << it - v_int.begin() << std::endl;
}
```

Failing this, my types in `mpl::vector` have a `type_trait<T>::ordinal` const hard-coded, I would like to avoid this if possible.

**Important Note**, I am also creating a `boost::variant` from the vector, and I see I can get at the ordinal by performing a runtime function `variant::which()`. However, this requires I create a dummy object with default-initialized values. This is quite uggly. If you know some other way of doing it with variant, that would be a solution to my problem as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you're looking for is a kind of indexOf feature, I guess the example from Boost.MPL doc concerning `find` will do the trick:

```
typedef vector<char,int,unsigned,long,unsigned long> types;
typedef find<types,unsigned>::type iter;

BOOST_MPL_ASSERT(( is_same< deref<iter>::type, unsigned > ));
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_RELATION( iter::pos::value, ==, 2 );
```

Comment: aah an `iter` has a `pos` element ? I couldn't find it in the itterator concepts documentation http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/iterators-concepts.html

Comment: Whilst I couldn't find a `pos` member when I was looking at the iterator concept documentation, it is shown in an example of the `mpl::find` documentation (same code fragment as you have shown).

Comment: @Hassan Syed: you might be interested in both this question and its answer regarding [undocumented iter::pos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666394/is-mpl-pos-an-undocumented-metafunction)

Answer (score 1):

Their is a metafunction in the itterator category to do just this, it is called [distance](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/distance.html).

p.s., apologies for answering my own question so quickly. I just stumbled on the solution.