# boost-mpl comparing iterators

Tags: c++, boost-mpl, template-meta-programming

Gosh, when working with mpl libraries, figuring out syntax is a hit-and-miss exerience ([previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043970/boostmplvector-getting-to-a-types-base-offset) ). What is the correct syntax to compare two mpl itterators -i.e., the `it != v.end()` test ?

```
template<typename T> 
struct get_type_ordinal
{
  rbl_type_ordinal_type operator()()
  {
    typedef typename boost::mpl::find<rbl_type_mpl_vector,T>::type it;
    typedef typename boost::mpl::end<rbl_type_mpl_vector>::type end;

    BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_NOT (( boost::mpl::equal_to< it, end >)); // problem here
    return it::pos::value;
   }
}
```

If I remove the assert the functor compiles and performs fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `boost::is_same<>`, that should do the trick.

Comment: I tried that earlier, it wasn't working, I was using `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT` though. For some reason it is working now. Thanks Nim.