# Get boost::variant's type index with boost::mpl

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl, boost-variant

boost::variant has member **types** which is some kind of boost::mpl structure.
Is there a way to get an index of type in that structure at compile time, so late in in runtime i could do

```
if(myVariantInstance.which() == typeIndex)
{
   /*...*/
}
```

Instead of

```
if(myVariantInstance.type() == typeid(ConcreteType))
{
  /*...*/
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [boost::mpl::vector - getting to a type's base-offset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043970/boostmplvector-getting-to-a-types-base-offset)

Comment: @cha5on, nope. I spent some time looking for solution myself and already seen that question. With `mpl::vector` it works like a charm, but with `variant`'s `types` it fails with missing `pos` member for type iterator. Consider this (http://pastebin.com/Hd01nJQy) snippet, second `static_assert` fails.

Comment: I see what you mean, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit convoluted, and there might be a better way, but you could use boost::mpl::copy.  Here's something that ought to work, based off of the example from your comment:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/find.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>

typedef boost::mpl::vector<int, long, char> MyMplVector;
typedef boost::mpl::find<MyMplVector, long>::type MyMplVectorIter;
static_assert(MyMplVectorIter::pos::value == 1, "Error");

typedef boost::variant<int, long, char> MyVariant;
typedef boost::mpl::vector<> EmptyVector;
typedef boost::mpl::copy<
  MyVariant::types,
  boost::mpl::back_inserter<EmptyVector>>::type ConcatType;

typedef boost::mpl::find<ConcatType, long>::type MyVariantTypesIter;
static_assert(MyVariantTypesIter::pos::value == 1, "Error");
```

Comment: Thanks. It might be useful later. For now i implemented `is` `static_visitor` like this: http://pastebin.com/Pfn44GFf

Answer (score 3):

I found solution for getting index of type in boost::variant without boost::mpl if you are interested in.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

#include <boost/variant/variant.hpp>

using myvariant = boost::variant<int, bool, double, int>;

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct type_index;

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct type_index<T, T, Ts ...>
    : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>
{};

template <typename T, typename U, typename ... Ts>
struct type_index<T, U, Ts ...>
    : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1 + type_index<T, Ts...>::value>
{};


template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct variant_first_same_type_idx;

template <typename T, typename Head, typename ... Tail>
struct variant_first_same_type_idx<T, boost::variant<Head, Tail ... >>
    : type_index<T, Head, Tail ...>
{};

int main()
{
    std::cout << variant_first_same_type_idx<int, myvariant>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << variant_first_same_type_idx<bool, myvariant>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << variant_first_same_type_idx<double, myvariant>::value << std::endl;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
0
1
2
```

**UPDATE FOR C++17:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <type_traits>

#include <boost/variant/variant.hpp>

using myvariant = boost::variant<int, bool, double, int>;

// std::type_identity in C++20
template <typename T>
struct type_identity
{
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr std::size_t get_same_type_idx(type_identity<boost::variant<Ts...>>)
{
    const bool is_same[]{std::is_same_v<Ts, T>...};
    // std::find in C++20
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof...(Ts); ++i)
    {
        if (is_same[i])
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    throw std::out_of_range("Type not found");
}

template <typename T, typename V>
constexpr std::size_t variant_first_same_type_idx = get_same_type_idx<T>(type_identity<V>{});

int main()
{
    std::cout << variant_first_same_type_idx<int, myvariant> << std::endl;
    std::cout << variant_first_same_type_idx<bool, myvariant> << std::endl;
    std::cout << variant_first_same_type_idx<double, myvariant> << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <boost/mpl/index_of.hpp>    
#include <iostream>

typedef boost::variant<int, std::string> VARIANT;
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &_rS, const VARIANT&_r)
{    switch (_r.which())
     {    default:
             return _rS << "what the *";
          case boost::mpl::index_of<VARIANT::types, int>::type::value:
             return _rS << boost::get<int>(_r);
          case boost::mpl::index_of<VARIANT::types, std::string>::type::value:
             return _rS << boost::get<std::string>(_r);
     }
}
```

PS. I was always curious about people using the visitor access pattern...

PPS. I know that one does not need to implement an output operator as boost::variant already provides one -- just for explanation purposes...